# Why does this string pass through as true in my RegEx statement match in my Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

Why does the following sentence:

```
let potential = "Kaline bypassed the Minors to join the Tigers at 18. By 20"
```

pass through this RegEx if statement:

```
if (potential.matches("(?i)No.\\s?-?\\s?[A-Z0-9]") ||
potential.matches("(?i)N0.\\s?-?\\s?[A-Z0-9]")) 
{
   print("in"
}

extension String {
    func matches(_ regex: String) -> Bool {
        return self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
}
```

Comment: "nors" matches your first regex. https://regex101.com/r/h7BhWb/1 What is your goal?

Comment: Ohhhh I see. Because of my optional spaces and - it's going right into the A-Z0-9. I'll fix it. thank you!

Comment: if `"No.-1"` Should be a successful match. I think the issue is that you forgot to escape the period.

Comment: Yep, that's it! Thank you Leo.

Comment: You can also use a single pattern instead of 2 using a character class `[0o]` to match each of the listed characters `(?i)N[0o]\\.\\s?-?\\s?[A-Z0-9]` https://regex101.com/r/8eSFAm/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking using 2 patterns, you can use a character class `[0o]` and use a single pattern.

As already mentioned in the comments, you have to escape the dot to match it literally or else it will match any character.

```
(?i)N[0o]\\.\\s?-?\\s?[A-Z0-9]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8eSFAm/1)